# Are questions about maths bookstores accepted here?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

Yesterday I was thinking about making a question about bookstores that sells mathematics books, ship internationally and accept PayPal. Is such a question acceptable here?

Comment: I take a stricter view of what is "mathematics". So in my personal opinion I would say that questions like that is off topic. Other users may be more generous in their interpretation.

Comment: I think that I'm slightly less strict than Willie, but I think that questions about bookstores might be pushing it. Generally you have Amazon, BookDepository, and well.. Google is your friend!

Comment: I suppose it depends on your motivation. Say you want to find your the linear algebra text for next semester, then you'd be pushing it. However, if the question is a general question about how to find more rare (for example, specialised research) maths texts cheaply then I think the community would be more sympathetic.